Register accessing and interrupt triggering
I want to handle a real register in my pc which uses intel i3 processor, handle means read and write.
At certain condition i want to raise a interrupt which prints the value in that register. I am a new learner to the kernel programming and this register level accessing.
How can i handle my register through kernel /(like altering the register value when user enter something),
how does physical address mapped to virtual address and how does it work, how to create interrupt .
"code and explanation"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

https://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/arch/blackfin/include/asm/io.h#L226  Linux kernel provides to map physical memory addresses to kernel virtual addresses.
